# Maximal element of a poset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I am currently studying Zorn's lemma and its my understanding that the definition of a maximal element is a primitive to the lemma.

From my understanding a maximal element $M$ of a partially ordered set  $(S,<)$  is an element $M \in S$ where, if $M \leq x $ for some $ x \in S$, then $x=m$.

This easilty illustrated when the set is {∅, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}}. Then the maximal elements are {3} and {1,2}.

But what if the partially ordered set i am considering is $(S,R)$.
So for example let S=P({a,b,c}) which is the power set of {a,b,c} and the relation $\subseteq$.
Now whats is the maximal element in this set?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think there's a typo: you mean the maximum elements are $\{3\}$ and $\{1,2\}$, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I have corrected it now.

Comment: @Elise: No, the maxim**al** elements are $\{3\}$ and $\{1,2\}$; that poset has no maxim**um** element. In the case of the power set of $\{a,b,c\}$ under $\subseteq$, $\{a,b,c\}$ is the unique maximal element and is also the maximum element.

Answer (score 3):

In general posets a maxim**um** element $M$ of $S$ is one such that $$\forall x \in S: x \le M$$

(all elements lie under $M$)
and a maxim**al** element $M$ of $S$ is one such that

$$\forall x \in S: (M \le x) \to (x=M)$$

(nothing is properly larger than $M$).

A maximum element is always a maximal element, and is always unique.

As you see in your fist example where $\{3\}$ and $\{1,2\}$ are both maximal, in general, we can have many non-comparable maximal elements, and this is typically the kind of poset Zorn is applied in.

In $\mathscr{P}(\{1,2,3\})$ we have a maximum element $\{1,2,3\}$. This is also the only maximal element.

Answer (score 1):

The only maximal element in the power set $S = P(\{a,b,c\})$ is $\{a,b,c\}$. Clearly $\{a,b,c\}$ is itself maximal and any other maximal subset $M$ of $\{a,b,c\}$ satisfies $M \subseteq \{a,b,c\} = x$ and thus by the maximality has $M = x= \{a,b,c\}$.

Comment: So when trying to find the maxiaml object its not  the $\leq$ relation i am looking for. I am looking at the relation that the set is ordered under?

Comment: If we have two different order relations on $S$ (such as $\subseteq$ and $R$), then we need to clarify which one we're talking about. A maximal element with respect to $\subseteq$ need not be maximal with respect to $R$.